# Static apple-app-site-association file with wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, php

In order to implement iOS's Universal Links, I need to serve an apple-app-site-association file at the root of my wordpress with the right `Content-type` (json).

How could I achieve that with wordpress ? And in general, how can i make any type of static ressource accessible with any custom content-type with Wordpress ?

A solution would be to put a apple-app-site-association.php file in my root folder, that returns the content with the right headers and to make it accessible at apple-app-site-association with url rewriting but is there a cleaner way using wordpress ?

I though about Custom Post Types but after a few researchs it seems like an heavy way to achieve such a simple goal.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

In my site config, add an SFTP user, then connect via sftp to my site directory at wpengine.com, followed by:

```
mkdir .well-known
cd .well-known
put apple-app-site-association
```

This uploads the file, which you can then verify is reachable at https://your.site/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

After that you'll need to contact the wp-engine.com support, I just opened a chat window on the website and waited for a support rep.

Then ask the rep to update nginx to add a content-type rule to set `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` to `application/json`.

Note this is approach wpengine.com recommends from this page: https://wpengine.com/support/htaccess-deprecation which discusses `.htaccess` deprecation. It explicitly says on that page if you need `AddType` support (which is what this is essentially) to contact Support.

The rep knew exactly what to do and had it mapped for me in nginx inside of five minutes.

You can verify your file works here: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/